# Save all dragged and dropped images in a Div to desktop?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I created a web page that has a Canvas element where I can drag and drop several images. I was also able to generate a single image of all of the dropped images on the the canvas. With help from this site I was able to do this in Javascript but had issues cross browser - would only work fully in Chrome. caniuse.com/#search=canvas.

This is what I used to generate Canvas image:

```
    function convertCanvasToImage() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

        var image_src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        window.open(image_src);

    }
```

Which would open a new window with image (with dragged and dropped images).

Because of the cross browser issues I was able to rebuild the page to support various features I was looking for to work using Javascript, HTML and JQuery that works across Chrome, IE, Safari and FF. No Canvas element used.

The re-created page uses a Div where the images are dropped instead of Canvas.

How do I generate a single image from these multiple dropped images and save them to the HDD via  a button?  That is, once all the images are dragged and dropped to the Div, to have the ability to click a Save button so that I can download the present location of all the images in the Div as a single PNG.

Surprisingly, the closest I've found so far in my searching has been a proprietary dollmakerscript from years ago that is using Javascript and PHP from what I could see. Most everything I've found here and elsewhere seems to refer to Canvas or to online snapshot services.

I created a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/babakt/hvXUK/ of the new page.  The "bktone" on the bottom is broken because it is referring to a folder of images that is not in the JSFiddle - it changes the background image used.

Thanks.

Comment: you can't without canvas or flash to do that client side. with server side script you can try to collect all images positions and names, and compose image (in case of php using gd )

Comment: eicto that is one of the paths I've been investigating (the dollmakerscript I mentioned above does this).  PHP/GD to generate a new page with the compiled image. The code I've looked at:  
<?php

header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = $_GET['text'];
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("images/button1.png");
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 210, 60);
$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($string)) / 2;
imagestring($im, 3, $px, 9, $string, $orange);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
This does not collect from the Div though. Any ideas?

Comment: you should collect from DOM using JS, send the data with ajax requests and generate image server side

Comment: Hi eicto...can you elaborate on collecting from DOM using Javascript?  The only thing I've found so far is this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_images.asp but the images I'm using are dragged and dropped into a DIV.

Comment: i think as you use jquery it is easy, but... you need to transfer images to make them children of div, not the tab area